# Optimize image on production environment

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, css, product-images

Is there any way to Optimize all product images under media folder directly on production server.

I was thinking to do by Gulp or Grunt but both required lots of installation on server which I think would not be the best workaround.

Is there any better solution you guys can suggest me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following plugin which doesn't require installation if any utility on your server at all which is great because most of the hosting companies won't allow to install utilities especially if you are on shared hosting.

This module uses cron job to compress your Magento catalog images instead of doing on the fly which could slow down your website. In the admin configuration you can define how many product images you want to optimize or compress the images at a time. It also support multiple well known APIs including Resmush.it, ImageOptim and Kraken API.

https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento-image-optimizer.html

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

To optimize all images, you can set the path to all images. The module works with cron job. Image optimization is done by gifsicle, jpegtran and OptiPNG, help the rating from Google Insights, find more details [here](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/image-optimizer.html).

Comment: @Monkviper - my answer helped you?